# C++ input operator overloading for class and vector

Tags: c++, vector, input, operator-overloading

I have a class with a constructor that takes a vector as an argument and some member functions that operate on the vector:

```
class myclass{
vector<double> myvec;
public:
    myclass(){ cout << "Constructor 1 " << endl; }

    myclass(const vector <double> &v){ "Constructor 2 " << endl; }

    ostream& print(ostream &s) const { //print function used in overloading output operator }

    double minimum(){ //return min value of vector }

    double maximum(){ //return max value of vector }
};
```

I have overloaded the input operator to take the values of a vector in a specific format: "<5: 1 2 3 4 5>" :

```
istream& operator>>(istream &s, myclass &mc) {
int size;
double item;
vector<double> tempvec;
char lpar, colon, rpar;
if (s >> lpar) {
    if ((s >> size >> colon) && (lpar == '<' && colon == ':')){
        tempvec[size];
        while(s >> item && rpar != '>'){
            tempvec.push_back(item);
        }
        mc = myclass(tempvec);
        s >> rpar;
    }else{
        s.setstate(ios::badbit);
    }
}
return s; 
}
```

I go to test my code:

```
int main(){
myclass mc;
cout << "Main Start" << endl;
while (cin >> mc)
    cout << mc << endl << mc.minimum() << endl << mc.maximum() << endl;
if (cin.bad()) cerr << "\nBad input\n\n";
cout << "Main Start" << endl;
return (0);
}
```

I run the code input the values in the format "<5: 1 2 3 4 5>", but instead of getting the min and max value printed out all I get is:

```
Constructor 1
Main Start
<5: 1 2 3 4 5>
Constructor 2
Main End
```

If I change the while loop in the operator overloading to:

```
while(s >> item >> rpar && rpar != '>'){
            tempvec.push_back(item);
        }
        mc = myclass(myvec);
```

I get the min and max when I test the code in main but only get half the inputs:

```
Constructor 1
Main Start
<5: 1 2 3 4 5>
Constructor 2
<2: 1 3>
1
3
```

I understand why this is:  item = 1, rpar = 2, rpar is not equal to '>', myvec.pushback(1) and so on...

So I think the error might to do with the while loop, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

**Edit:**

So I included a count to compare the number of inputs to the size:

```
while(s >> item && count < size && rpar != '>'){
        tempvec.push_back(item);
        ++count; // count++ doesnt change anything
    }
    mc = myclass(tempvec);
    s >> rpar;
```

I now get:

```
Constructor 1
Main Start
<5: 1 2 3 4 5>
Constructor 2
<4: 1 2 3 4>
1
4
Main End
```

The last value is not being included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two bugs in the same line in your overloaded `>>` operator.

```
    while(s >> item && rpar != '>'){
```

1. `rpar` is not initialized before its value is compared here. This is undefined behavior.
2. The likely result of this undefined behavior is that `rpar` will be some garbage, and there's only 1 in 256 chance that it will be the '>' character. Otherwise this comparison will always be true, and this `while` loop is logically equivalent to:

   ```
   while (s >> item)
   ```

This means that this `while` loop will continue to run until the input stream either goes into failed state, or until it reaches the end of the file.

This means that when your `>>` operator overload returns, the stream is guaranteed to be in an error or in a failed state. This means that in your main function:

```
while (cin >> mc)
```

will never be true, and that's why you do not get your minimum and maximum values shown.

You need to:

1. Definitely fix the undefined behavior.
2. Probably fix the logic in your `>>` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I may have fixed my problem I changed the logic and so I'm now using a for-loop, I could have still used a while-loop but I think a for-loop is better:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size; ++i){
            s >> item;
            tempvec.push_back(item);
        }
        if (s >> rpar && rpar == '>'){
            mc = myclass(tempvec);
        }
```

Hopefully this is correct.